# Why the except element doesn't recognize the variable "result"

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

```
try:
   x = 5
   y = 0
   result = x/y
   print(result)
except Exception:
   y = 1
   print(result)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Because trying to assign to result is the exact thing that failed (strictly: calculating the value to assign).

Comment: What value do you think ``result`` has in the ``except`` clause?

Answer (score 0):

When you run this line of your code, `result = x/y`, the interpreter goes through three steps.

1. Look up the values of the names `x` and `y`.
2. Divide them.
3. Bind the name `result` to the result of the division.

When `y` is `0`, the division in step 2 fails. That means that step 3 is never reached, so nothing gets bound to `result`. This leads to your error when you try to print it later.

Note that the division happens right away when the `x/y` expression is attempted. The expression is not saved and re-done if the inputs are changed. So setting `y` to `1` in the `except` block doesn't reattempt the division, and `result` remains undefined. If you want to redo it, you need to do it explicitly:

```
except:
    y = 1
    result = x/y
    print(result)
```